# repotting a dracaena marginata plant

Tags: repotting

I have had this plant (dracaena marginata) for some time and it is now drooping as it is now 3ft tall.  A new sprout is growing in the same pot.  Is there a way to cut off the tall part of the plant and repot it.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Brenda  it may help to see an image of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy, just start at the top of the stems with leaves and cut the stem with a sterile and sharp knife or blade a few inches down from the part of the stem that has leaves and stick it in a jar with water, changing the water once every week or more often if the water goes cloudy. It should grow some roots over the next 2-4 months.

Next, take 9 inch cuttings of the leafless parts of the stem and lay them flat on  moist gritty well draining cactus mix in a sed tray, These may decide to bud over 6 months but your hope is it will grow some roots first at nodes but the success of this method is about 20-25% max but nothing ventured, nothing gained eh?

Keep taking cuttings until you get to a neater piece of 'stick' and in the next 6 months the old plant will at some point on the remaining stalk(s) begin to throw out some new buds which will then grow into new shoots and stems.

Good luck.